# Как получить индекс элемента при клике?

Tags: javascript

Привет. Есть такой код

```
<div class='wrapper'>
<div class='dot'></div>
<div class='dot'></div>
<div class='dot'></div>
<div class='dot'></div>
<div class='dot'></div>
<div class='dot'></div>
<div class='dot'></div>
</div>
```

Через команду

```
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dots');
```

Получил массив с dot.

Как при клике на каждый в console высвечивалось его index
Кликаю на первый элемент в консоль его индекс(0)

очень прошу дать пример кода,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8802111/6104996

Comment: но indexOf тут не работает. как быть? <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false --> <!-- language: lang-js --> var cont = document.getElementById("container"); var dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot'); cont.addEventListener("click", function(event) { console.log(dots.indexOf(event.target)); }); <!-- language: lang-html --> <div id='container'> <div class='dot'>as1</div> <div class='dot'>sa2</div> <div class='dot'>as3</div> <div class='dot'>as4</div> </div> <!-- end snippet -->

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как отслеживать изменение класса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/781248/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0)

Answer (score 6):

### Вариант 1 (плохой, но очевидный):

```
dots.forEach(function(dot, i) {
    dot.addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log(i);
    });
});
```

Плох он тем, что приходится навешивать слишком много (а точнее, неоправданно много) обработчиков.

Вместо `foreach()` можно, разумеется, воспользоваться и простым циклом:

```
var i, length = dots.length;

for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    dots[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log(i);
    });
}
```

### Вариант 2 (получше):

Для его реализации необходимо обернуть необходимые элементы в родительский элемент, своего рода "контейнер" (предположим, у него `id = cont`).

Тогда можно навесить один обработчик события на этот контейнер:

```
var cont = document.getElementById("cont");

cont.addEventListener("click", function(event) { // навешиваем один обработчик на родительский элемент
    console.log(dots.indexOf(event.target)); // в свойстве `target` будет содержаться непосредственно тот элемент, по которому кликнули
});
```

Но в этом случае придется искать индекс элемента в массиве отдельно (метод `indexOf()`).

Также стоит помнить, что искомого элемента в массиве может не быть (кликнули не на элемент с классом `dot`), а куда-нибудь мимо (но все еще в пределах родительского блока). В этом случае стоит сразу проверить, есть ли элемент в массиве, а затем уже выводить его индекс, если элемент найден - стандартная процедура:

```
cont.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var index = dots.indexOf(event.target);

    if (~index) {
        console.log(index);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ОШИБКИ

1. Внимательнее выписывайте селекторы. У вас в html файле указан `class='dot'`, а в скрипте вы получаете элементы с классом `dots`
2. С помощью метода `.getElementsByClassName()` вы получаете не массив, а псевдомассив, у которого нет метода `.indexOf()`.

Для выполнения вашей задачи, я предлагаю конвертировать псевдомассив `dots` в массив с помощью `Array.from()` и навесить обработчик событий на родительский элемент, чтобы при добавлении новых элементов эта функция работала и для них.

РЕШЕНИЕ

```js
var wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');

wrapper.addEventListener('click', event => {
    console.log(Array.from(dots).indexOf(event.target));
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <div class='dot'>1</div>
        <div class='dot'>2</div>
        <div class='dot'>3</div>
        <div class='dot'>4</div>
        <div class='dot'>5</div>
        <div class='dot'>6</div>
        <div class='dot'>7</div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```