# Как отслеживать изменение класса

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добры день есть такая задачка, с такой разметкой

```
<div class='wrapper'>
<div class='item'>
<div class='item'>
<div class='item active'>
<div class='item'>
</div>
```

При свайпе другого элемента у item меняется класс( т.е повесить обработчик в другом месте не вариант) мне надо отслеживать изменение класса, и как только он изменился получать индекс нового элемента с классом active

Не думаю что такое вообще возможно но решил спросить все же:)

Comment: Ты как то реагируй, когда тебе люди помогают...

Comment: Вообще - mutation obserber, но тебе это не надо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить индекс элемента массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706956/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Answer (score 3):

```js
var item = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
  item[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
      item[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
    item[i].classList.add('active');
    console.log('индекс элемента---', i);
  })

}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='item'>item</div>
  <div class='item'>item</div>
  <div class='item active'>item</div>
  <div class='item'>item</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

что-то вроде этого

```
function lookingForActive() {
    let items = document.body.querySelectorAll('.wrapper .item');

    items.forEach(function(value, i, arr) {
        if (value.classList.contains("active")) {
            retutn(i);
        }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, повесить обработчики на все эти элементы, и проверять наличие класса.
Если Вы используете jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', 'div.item', function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {/* then todo */};
});
```