# как получить индекс элемента массива с помощью event js?

Tags: javascript

```
<body>
<div id ='container'>
    <div class='dot'>as1</div>
    <div class='dot'>sa2</div>
    <div class='dot'>as3</div>
    <div class='dot'>as4</div>
</div>
<script>
    var cont = document.getElementById("container");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');
        cont.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            console.log(dots.indexOf(event.target)); // indexOf не работает
        });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как отслеживать изменение класса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/781248/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0)

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByClassName` возвращает не массив, а похожий на массив набор элементов:

```js
var cont = document.getElementById("container");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');
cont.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log(Array.prototype.indexOf.call(dots, event.target)); // indexOf работает
});
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div class='dot'>as1</div>
  <div class='dot'>sa2</div>
  <div class='dot'>as3</div>
  <div class='dot'>as4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Или через добавленный в es6 оператор `...`

```js
var cont = document.getElementById("container");
cont.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log([...document.getElementsByClassName('dot')].indexOf(event.target)); // indexOf работает
});
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div class='dot'>as1</div>
  <div class='dot'>sa2</div>
  <div class='dot'>as3</div>
  <div class='dot'>as4</div>
</div>
```